# Choosing a calendar

Tags: iphone, ios, nscalendar

This is a simple question, there are several IOS calendar frameworks on github.com, the problem is that I can't find one that let me load specific dates by code, an example:

I have these dates:

12-11-2003

13-11-2003

14-11-2003

I want to load them by code and display them on the calendar.

Can someone point me a good calendar framework with this option so that I can add him to my current project.

Sorry for my bad english, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[THIS](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal) is a good calendar i have ever seen.. and it gives the good user experience to users, because it looks like a default calendar which comes with iphone.